# delete json object form array with php

Tags: php, json, object

I want to delete an element from json array with php

```
[{"userid":"20"},{"userid":"17"},{"userid":"18"}]
```

I want to make It like That

```
[{"userid":"20"},{"userid":"18"}]
```

Comment: http://php.net/unset

Comment: If it is still a topic: I guess the problem is somewere else in your code, maybe you can share more details?

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = json_decode('[{"userid":"20"},{"userid":"17"},{"userid":"18"}]');

foreach ($array as $key=>$element) {
    if ($element->userid == "17") {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}

// delete the row with the index
$arrayFinal = array_values($array);
$output = json_encode($arrayFinal);

echo $output;
```

Comment: This is the output `{"0":{"userid":"20"},"2":{"userid":"18"}}` but i don't want that key [**0, 2**]

Comment: @AnaJentel Check my answer. It's working correctly.

Comment: I know that it's working but I don't want to show 0, 2 keys of all objects

Comment: My answer is working just like you want. There is not 0, 2 keys. The output is `[{"userid":"20"},{"userid":"18"}]`. Please, check it again.

Comment: @Spectarion solution is: $arrayFinal = array_values($array);
$output = json_encode($arrayFinal);

echo $output;

Answer (score 2):

**If you know the element index:**

```
unset($array[1]); // 1 is the index of element.
```

**If you don't know the element index:**

```
// Deserialize the JSON into associative array.
$users = json_decode('[{"userid":"20"},{"userid":"17"},{"userid":"18"}]', true);

// For each user and it's index in array of users.
foreach ($users as $index => $user) {
    // If currently iterated user id is equals to 17.
    if ($user["userid"] == 17) {
        // Remove it from an array of users.
        unset($users[$index]);
        // Stop loop execution.
        break;
    }
}

// Echo all elements inside an array of users as JSON.
echo json_encode(array_values($users));
```